# Best way to inform users after file upload

Tags: notifications

I'm searching for a good solution to inform users after a file was uploaded (with standard upload URL: `...file/add`).

I would solve this with rules, but I can't find the right events for this.
Has anybody a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the [Entity Rules](https://drupal.org/project/entity_rules) module? I believe this is exactly what that module is for.

I did a brief check and you can create a reaction rule on a Create Entity action and then check the type of that entity.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, with this module I got the events I need to check for. With it I could solve the first step, but the 2. is a little bit more complex. 
The files were tagged with a term, a term stands for a role. Now only the users which have the specific role, which belongs to the term, should get an email - not all of the users.

Comment: If you're trying to relate a taxonomy term representing a role to users with that role, you may find some difficulty in doing so. The best way I could see doing that is having a Rule for each role. That way you could check the Term value you set on the File entity and send the email to all users of a specific role. If you only have a few terms/roles to relate, then that shouldn't be a problem. If you have many [and/or it may change overtime] then this option may not work and you'd need to figure out a different way to relate the Term to the Role.

Comment: If the answer solved your initially posted question please consider marking it as such. Thanks!